# Typical GSM current profile

Tags: current-measurement, gsm, modem

I'm working with GSM modem and I'm wondering if anyone has come across any sort of measured or typical GSM current profiles for various actions such as:

- Connecting to base station
- Sending a SMS
- Voice call
- During an active data connection

I know the general trend of what the current consumption should look like when it is transmitting based upon frame rate and slot-time, what I'm looking for is more coarse view.  For example when sending a SMS message it transmits for N number of slots.

Answer (score 2):

I used some generic modules, so here are some values to work with:

- voice call: 250 - 300 mA (unactive unused bursts: 20 - 50 mA)
- GPRS (2Tx, 3Rx slots): 340 - 410 mA

This assumes having a matched antenna. The current consumption itself depends on the transmitted power and is thus dependend on the network. If you have a highly unmatched antenna, a voice call can draw up to 2500 mA.

Comment: What chipset were you using?

Comment: @Kortuk [LEON-G200](http://www.u-blox.com/de/wireless-modules/gsm-gprs-modules/leon-gsm-module-family.html)

Comment: I meant that it is probably worth placing that in the answer. Did the datasheet for the chipset not give you this information?

Comment: @Kortuk It did in some part.

Answer (score 0):

Siemens, some time ago, made many GSM modules widely by machine-to-machine systems, like TC25, TC35, TC65, with very detailed technical data manuals. Some has good graphs showing the current rise time and peak duration, etc.

Try search, like
http://www.op5.com/manuals/extras/op5_TC65_GSM_module_manual.pdf